# Threaded messaging on pubnub

Tags: pubnub

We want to create threads for messages within a chat channel on Pubnub. For example, someone could respond to a specific message in a channel by 'creating a thread' and starting to chat. Is there a prescribed way to model this behavior? If so, can you please reference documentation?

This is the behavior you see in slack, for reference.

Answer (score 4):

There's no ready-made solution documented for threaded messaging. However, building a hierarchical relationship between messages could be achieved by tagging them with metadata (using PN Objects and/or MessageActions) and then some coding on your end to maintain and handle their relationship.

You could use the time token of the thread's first message as the key, group messages based on it, and use the messages' own time tokens to generate the order for the UI.

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#methods

Here's the high-level design for doing this:

- A message is published to a channel with the name `chat_11223344` (channel name uses `chat_` as a prefix for all chat channels and a generated id - keeping it short here but you can use a uuid generator for this). That publish returns a *publish timetoken*, something like this: `16183330926487763`.
- Using [PN Objects](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/channels/metadata), your display name for the channel can be set along with a description.
- In your chat UI, you allow a person to create a thread on that message. The message gets published to a channel named `chat_11223344.16183330926487763` , using the publish timetoken of the top-level message as the "sub-channel" name.
- So that you can easily identify top-level messages that are threaded, you would add a [MessageAction](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/messages/actions) to that message when the first "threaded" message is published. You may also want to add custom Channel Metadata (PN Objects, again) to add a `"isThreaded":true` key/value.

Answer (score 2):

So with PubNub you can append meta data to either the message itself or PubNub has a section called meta (https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#methods).

An example payload could be:

```
{
  "type":"message",
  "payload":"What do people want for lunch? Pizza?",
  "sender":"me",
  "sent":1618336638,
  "messageActive":true,
  "channel":"main",
  "messageID":"main.abc123"
}
```

where `abc123` is a uuid that references that message.
When someone wants to thread a message you can append `"threaded":true` variable to the object.

```
    {
      ...
      "messageID":"main.abc123",
      "threaded":true,
      ...
    }
```

Now your UI knows that there is a breakout thread, using `main.abc123.thread` as the channelID for that specific thread.
Your app then subscribes to the new channel `main.abc123.thread` and you can use `fetchMessages();` to get history messages as well as new real time messages.